# Existence of a function that looks like Fejer Kernel

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

defined as
$$
w_{N}(x)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} W_{N}(n) e^{2 \pi i n x}=\sum_{n=-N}^{N}\left(1-\frac{|n|}{N+1}\right) e^{2 \pi i n x}
$$
has this shape that is periodic and relative small value between peaks (flat). Since the Fejer kernel is the sum of sinusoidal functions with different frequency, I was wondering if I can construct this function with some sinusoidal elements with same frequency. Or is there a function looks like this but with different functional form?

Any help is appreciated.

[image: Fejer kernel]